# Phonegap iOS: How to update the content when return with multitasking

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

Hi I have an issue when there is no gps enabled an message is shown, then you go to settings and activate the gps (Location Services: On) and go back to the app and it doesn't refreshes?
How can I detect that event and refresh the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely looking for the `- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application` method of your app delegate.

Implement this method, and add your code that checks for GPS availability. The method will be called whenever your application is brought from background (inactive) to the foreground (active). It is not called when the application initially launched.

Comment: I was looking for a way to do this with Phonegap/Cordova 1.7.0 if its possible with it's functions: document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);  
[link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#resume)

Comment: Forget what I posted, just discovered phonegap should be doing this for you already (they implement the method above and call PhoneGap.fireDocumentEvent('resume');"). Since this is what you were looking for, I probably can't help you on why its not working.

Comment: Yes it's working, and with the iOS quirk it's ok for android and iOS, I should probably close the question.